# How do I approach a professor for a Ph.D. Admission?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, india

It is about 10 km between my house and the professor's office (at the university). I have emailed the professor but have not received any response.

The professor doesn't know me. He works in my area of interest. I want to work with this professor.

Moreover, a government funding agency offers me a Ph.D. scholarship.

Ph.D. admissions are taken through a direct interview (viva) at that university.

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: @Buffy India  .My residence is in New Delhi

Comment: "It is about 10 km between my house and the professor's office" Die you actually physically drop by at their office to talk, then?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi To be honest, I'm a little afraid to speak with the professor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to put your fears aside and go visit him. Make an appointment, perhaps through the university. Put together a CV and a couple of ideas about research and just do it.

It is natural to lack confidence for many people, but it is only through practice that you get over it. And you will have to interact with him in any case if you are accepted as his student.

If you know anyone at your current institution who might know him, ask them about what to expect. Or ask them about what to expect in an admissions interview in India in any case.

I don't know why you haven't gotten any response. I don't know whether the university is currently "in session" or not. I don't know what you put in your email. Sometimes too much or too little can be an issue. But seek advice locally on what is expected. Some people are just too busy to respond to blind emails. Make an appointment. Go. Good luck.

---

Caveat, I don't know how doctoral admissions works in India. In the US, you apply to a department and its admissions committee, not a professor. In Germany, IIRC, it is usually to the professor.